# ReSharper support for QUnit tests doesn't recognize Chutzpah Template import feature

Tags: javascript, resharper, qunit

I have a bunch of QUnit tests. I am testing my code against html templates. For these tests I am using HTML template importing feature.

I have the following on the top of the JavaScript test file.

```
///<template path="mytemplate.html" mode="script" id="mytemplate" type="text/ng-template" />
```

If I run the tests using the VS 2015 Chutzpah plugin, the tests run fine but they fail if I use ReShaper(ReShaper ultimate 10.2). ReShaper won't recognize the template reference.

Has anyone tried to get ReShaper to run QUnit tests by using templates ? If this is not possible on ReShaper, has anyone tried to access html files during there QUnit tests which will work with ReShaper ?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at ReSharper documentation looks like Reshaper doesn't really support Chutzpah. ReSharper will run Jasmine and QUnit.

ReShaper will however work with a custom html harness which could be generated by chutzpah.

This is something that unfortunately doesn't work for me because the html templates could change during development.

Maybe QUnit has a way to inject html templates in QUnit fixture.